# Nginx throwing 404 for request, instead of performing try_files

Tags: nginx

I have the following block in my nginx configuration file:

```
location /cat {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?url=$uri;
}
```

When I try any of the following URLs, this works as expected:

```
http://example.com/cat/test
http://example.com/cat/test/test
http://example.com/cat/t
```

The following, however, do not. Instead of a redirect, I get a 404 error.

```
http://example.com/cat/test/
http://example.com/cat/test/test/
http://example.com/cat/t/
```

I'm not very experienced with nginx, so let me know what further information might be needed. This has me quite stumped.

Edit: I did come across this, but I would prefer to avoid using rewrite (for the sake of efficiency), plus this seems like an unnecessary band-aid:
https://serverfault.com/questions/755646/nginx-use-try-files-to-serve-file-instead-of-directory

Edit 2: Here is the full config

```
server {
    listen 64.40.99.86:80;

    server_name example.com;
    server_name www.example.com;

    client_max_body_size 128m;

    root "/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs";
    access_log "/var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/logs/proxy_access_log";
    error_log "/var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/logs/proxy_error_log";

    if ($host ~* ^example.com$) {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com$1 permanent;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://64.40.99.86:7080;
        proxy_set_header Host        $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Accel-Internal /internal-nginx-static-location;
        access_log off;
    }

    location /internal-nginx-static-location/ {
        alias /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/;
        add_header X-Powered-By PleskLin;
        internal;
    }

    location ~ ^/~(.+?)(/.*?\.php)(/.*)?$ {
        alias /var/www/vhosts/example.com/web_users/$1/$2;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.php)(/?.+)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_pass "unix:///var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/php-fpm.sock";
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
    }

    location ~ ^/~(.+?)(/.*)?$ {
        proxy_pass http://64.40.99.86:7080;
        proxy_set_header Host        $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Accel-Internal /internal-nginx-static-location;
        access_log off;
    }

    location ~ \.php(/.*)?$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.php)(/?.+)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_pass "unix:///var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/php-fpm.sock";
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
    }

    location ~ /$ {
        index index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml index.htm index.shtml;
    }

    location /cat {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?url=$uri;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show full nginx's config

Comment: Added the full configuration file

Comment: Your `location ~ /$` "eats" requests with trailing slash so they have no chance to get to last location. Read the docs on location directive carefully